# Using a variable with re.compile

Tags: python, variables, beautifulsoup

```
    for issn in inputList:
      link = journalresults.find('a', attrs={'href' : re.compile(issn + '$')})
```

I am trying to use the variable 'issn' with re.compile and append '$' after it but have tried umpteen combinations while searching for a resolution that all have come up unsucessful.

Obviously I am missing something simple. I am just looking to find 'issn' within the href attribute. It appears at the end so that is why I want to append $ after the 'issn' variable.

Edit: using the comment to try 'print >>sys.stderr, repr(issn)', I see there is a newline after the issn that I needed to strip. Thank you for the newbie help.

Comment: did you check what type the variable `issn` is? Use `print >>sys.stderr, repr(issn)` and check what you get. Additionally, what error message is printed?

Comment: Do you want the literal `$` or the end of string?

Comment: What hochl said, plus the error you're getting might give some insights.

Comment: You need to make sure that `issn` is a string and contains what you want. Did you check that? Did you debug your program, for example by using `import pdb` at the top and using `pdb.set_trace()` right before the compile statement?

Comment: Using the comment to try 'print >>sys.stderr, repr(issn)', I see there is a newline after the issn that I needed to strip. Thank you for the newbie help.

Comment: Good we could help you. I'll write my comment as a reply so you can accept it and close this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check what type the variable `issn` is? Use `print >>sys.stderr, repr(issn)` and check what you get. Additionally, what error message is printed? Did you debug your program, for example by using import pdb at the top and using pdb.set_trace() right before the compile statement?